# Salesforce Profile deployment

Tags: deployment, profile, ant

I have some issue with one profile deployment. For deployment we are using Ant Migration Tool. In Pull Request we have some properties set up as false, in package for deployment also, but after deployment in target org, these parameters are visible as true.
We were trying to do it twice and we recognize this issue again.

Anyone had the same problem?

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: What are the properties you are referring to? Can you add more details of the steps to reproduce this behavior?Thanks

Comment: Is this a new Profile? Have you tried to clone the Minimum Access profile to manually create the profile with the same name in the destination and then push this change - essentially update instead of a create? The reason is that when you create a Profile with the API, it clones the Standard User (or Standard Platform) profile and then overrides with incoming permissions. So, eliminating that issue.

Comment: We recognized that this properties are impossible to change for specific license type. 
Deployment didn't throw any messages, that's why we wera a bit confused, now we are fine with that issue.